# Вытащить `ELEMENT_ID`в глобальную переменную

Tags: php, битрикс

Добрый день. Очень нужна ваша помощь! У меня по ссылке`/catalog/tovary-dlya-ofisa-kantstovary/demonstratsionnoe-oborudovanie/doski-dlya-pisma-i-informatsii-25/305501/` открывается страница детального просмотра каталога, то есть карточка товара. 
ЧПУ ссылки: `/catalog/#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_ID#` Мне нужно вытащить `ELEMENT_ID`в глобальную переменную фильтра, что-то типа этого:

```
<?$GLOBALS['arrFilter'] = array("PROPERTY_53" => $_REQUEST["ELEMENT_ID"]);?> <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog", 
    "catalog_new", 
    array(
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`

Не знаю просто как сформулировать его поточнее.В общем нужно как то через API делал, чтобы если мы меняем ЧПУ на `/catalog/#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#` он брал этот ID из кода.

```
`<? $iblock = 4; //id инфоблока
$code = $GET["ELEMENT_CODE"];//нужно получить это значение из адресной строки 
$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "CODE","DETAIL_PAGE_URL");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>$iblock, "CODE"=>$code);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array(), $arSelect)->Fetch();

echo $res["ID"];

 ?>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам нужно получить последний элемент из URL-Path, можно сделать так:

```
$id = end(explode(trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'), '/'));
```

Сначала получаем URL-Path, тримим его, удаляя внешние `/`, делим на массив по сепаратору `/`, берем последний элемент.

P.S. а вообще, вопрос не совсем понятен. Ответил на вопрос, как понял.

[$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php), [end()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.end.php), [trim()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php), [explode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php).

Comment: Это костыль получается, если в настройки чпу выставить вместо '/catalog/#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_ID#/' '/catalog/#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#', то не будет работать.

Comment: @Николай А в этом случае ^ что-то работать вообще-то будет? /catalog/12345678` - и как с этим разбираться?

Comment: Получилось, сделал так `<? $iblock = 4; //id инфоблока
$id = end(explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "CODE","DETAIL_PAGE_URL");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>$iblock, "CODE"=>$id);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array(), $arSelect)->Fetch();

$GLOBALS["TOVAR_ID"]= $res["ID"];

 ?>` Хоть и костыльно немного, но работает.

Answer (score 2):

В шаблоне карточки товара (catalog.element) нужно прописать:

```
$GLOBALS['ID'] = $arResult['ID'];
```

ниже по коду в любом компоненте id товара будет доступен через $GLOBALS['ID']

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно выше передать по коду. Отложенную функцию прошу не предлагать) Мне кажется, должно проще как то всё быть

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$urlData   = parse_url('/catalog/#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_ID#');
$fragment  = explode('/', $urlData['fragment']);
$elementId = array_pop($fragment);
```

Comment: А если заменить ЧПУ '/catalog/#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE# ' будет работать?

Comment: Данный пример рассчитывает на абсолютно любой ЧПУ с #ELEMENT_ID# в конце. Отвечая на ваш вопрос - в переменной $elementId будет #ELEMENT_CODE#

Comment: Пробую `$link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlData   = parse_url($link);
$fragment  = explode('/', $urlData['fragment']);
$elementId = array_pop($fragment);
echo $elementId;
` но ничего не выводит

Comment: Напишите, что у вас приходит в переменную $urlData

Comment: Выводит array и всё

Comment: Сделайте print_r($urlData); Что выводит?

Comment: print_r($urlData) выводит array. Спасибо за отклик, уже разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю просто как сформулировать его поточнее. В общем, как то через API делал, что если мы меняем ЧПУ на `/catalog/#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#` он брал этот ID из кода.

```
<?  
    $iblock = 4; //id инфоблока
    $code = $_GET["ELEMENT_CODE"]; //нужно получить это значение из адресной строки 
    $arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "CODE", "DETAIL_PAGE_URL");
    $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => $iblock, "CODE" => $code);
    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array(), $arSelect)->Fetch();

    echo $res["ID"];
?>
```